# takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given when passing a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python3.x script that I am passing a string as an argument.  If I take the literal string it works, but when I pass it as a variable I get:
"takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

network_id and mTags are populated on a for loop above, but I took this piece of code and ran it manually and got the same response.  If I insert after the network_id, the value of mTags without the "" it processes correctly, but this way it doesn't.  Need help understanding what is going on to try to fix this.

```
network_id = N_573083052582975205

mTags = "tags=['1504007', '3850357_all', '3850373_all']"

response = dashboard.networks.updateNetwork(network_id, mTags)
return response
```

Comment: can you post the error traceback and a working example?

Comment: 'https://api.meraki.com/api/v1', 'single_request_timeout': 60, 'certificate_path': '', 'requests_proxy': '', 'wait_on_rate_limit': True, 'nginx_429_retry_wait_time': 60, 'action_batch_retry_wait_time': 60, 'retry_4xx_error': False, 'retry_4xx_error_wait_time': 60, 'maximum_retries': 2, 'simulate': False, 'be_geo_id': None, 'caller': None}
tags=['1504007', '3850357_all', '3850373_all']
<class 'str'>
updateNetwork() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: This is the response I get back from the script above.

Comment: Is the `dashboard.networks` class part of your code, or is it a module?  It is apparently a class method that only wants one parameter.

Comment: and what is `dashboard.networks`? can you provide a working example, it will make it easier to give an answer

Comment: Also this is a Meraki api call I am not using any classes on my side.  This is just a simple script that I parse an excel file and populate the API.

Comment: A working example would be "response = dashboard.networks.updateNetwork(network_id, tags=['1504007', '3850357_all', '3850373_all'])"

Comment: from the [docs](https://developer.cisco.com/meraki/api-v1/#!update-network), `tags` is a keyword, not positional argument. read up on Python keyword arguments!

Comment: ahhh that makes sense.  I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're a little confused between parameter types and how parameters are passed.

In the [source code](https://github.com/meraki/dashboard-api-python/blob/master/meraki/api/networks.py#L26-L37), `updateNetwork` is a method and the signature is `updateNetwork(self, networkId, **kwargs)`.

When you use a method of the class the `self` is automatically passed in as whatever the instance the method is an attribute of.

You're doing

```
dashboard.networks.updateNetwork(network_id, mTags)
```

Internally this is calling:

```
updateNetwork(dashboard.networks, network_id, mTags)
```

But this doesn't match the signature. In the signature there can be two position arguments, and the rest must be keyword arguments.

Next problem is that what you have assigned to `mTags` is a string. But `tags` should actually be a list. You can solve this by unquoting the string and getting rid of the `mTags` assignment which is useless.

In total you would have:

```
tags = ['1504007', '3850357_all', '3850373_all']
response = dashboard.networks.updateNetwork(network_id, tags=tags)
```